# Limit results in PHP using while loop

Tags: php

I have a list of returned subcategories. I only have access to the template display and not to the MySQL query so no, I can't limit the query.

Right now all the results are returned. I would like to limit the list to 5, and then add a "more" link if there are more than 5 results.

I know I did this wrong because I don't think `count` is actually tied to the `foreach`:

```
<ul class="sub-categories">
    <?php
    while (count($category->getChildren()) <= 5) { // line I added for while loop
        foreach ($category->getChildren() as $child) {
            if (!$child->totalItemCount())
                continue;

            $link = $this->app->route->category($child);
            $item_count = ($this->params->get('template.show_sub_categories_item_count')) ? ' <span>('.$child->totalItemCount().')</span>' : '';
                echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$child->name.'">'.$child->name.'</a>'.$item_count.'</li>';
        }
    } // line I added for while loop
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track within the `foreach` and `break;` when you've reached the limit:

```
<ul class="sub-categories">
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($category->getChildren() as $child) {
            if (!$child->totalItemCount()) continue;
            $i++; if($i>5) break;
            $link = $this->app->route->category($child);
            $item_count = ($this->params->get('template.show_sub_categories_item_count')) ? ' <span>('.$child->totalItemCount().')</span>' : '';
            echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$child->name.'">'.$child->name.'</a>'.$item_count.'</li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: which is considered "better form" and why?

Comment: normally I would use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` or while when you need to iterate through objects.

Comment: @liz, you may want to move the increment *after* the `if (!$child->totalItemCount()) continue;` line, so you always have 5 results.

Comment: @liz, sorry about that, I was just throwing out code and didn't think about it too much. The second solution wouldn't work because it loops through all of the items before it tests the `while` expression again.